# Error in tcg-op.h Header file

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Hi i'm getting this error while compiling qemu

```
In file included from /home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/tcg/tcg.h:117:0,
                 from /home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/exec.c:29:
/home/epuser/ajayku/final_test/qemu/qemu-1.6.0/tcg/tcg-op.h:26:1: error: expected identifier before ‘int’
make[1]: *** [exec.o] Error 1
```

and the initial content of "tcg-op.h" file is :

```
int gen_new_label(void);

static inline void tcg_gen_op0(TCGOpcode opc)
{
     *tcg_ctx.gen_opc_ptr++ = opc;
}

 static inline void tcg_gen_op1_i32(TCGOpcode opc, TCGv_i32 arg1)
{
    *tcg_ctx.gen_opc_ptr++ = opc;
    *tcg_ctx.gen_opparam_ptr++ = GET_TCGV_I32(arg1);
}
```

Comment: Could you post all of your code?  You probably forgot a semicolon before the #include.

Comment: The problem is probably before the headaer inclusion